# Last traded Price - "Last Price Line" as a fixed variable

Tags: pine-script

In Tradingview, I want to get the last traded price of a stock in Pine Script as a fixed Variable. In Built "close" would not suffice as this changes for each bar. As an example in the tradingview charts we have "Last Price Line" which is a constant line of the last traded price as shown in the Image

https://www.tradingview.com/x/5KVDU8h7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in variable 'close' is the latest traded price. Here's a script that draws a yellow dotted line at last traded price and as you can see it is always identical to the default "last price line" drawn by tradingview. If you want to access last traded price of previous bars, you can do it by looking up close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMdwr.png)..close[2]..close[n] where n is number of bars back from the current bar.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var line _lpLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0, extend=extend.left, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.yellow)

_lastTradedPrice = close
line.set_xy1(_lpLine, bar_index-1, _lastTradedPrice)
line.set_xy2(_lpLine, bar_index, _lastTradedPrice)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Urso...But my requirement is to have the last traded price as a fixed variable which i can use as a multiplier in my program. This is the link for the program that i am trying to write with explanation "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630788/how-to-find-the-current-latest-price-of-the-selected-stock-in-pine-code-in-tradi"

Comment: The final solution the the problem was Move to Existing Pane of the basic Indicator code: //@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Comparative", shorttitle="RSC", overlay=false)
src = input(close, title="Source")
comparativeTickerId = input("NIFTY", type=input.symbol, title="Comparative Symbol")
comparativeSymbol = security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, close)
rs=src/comparativeSymbol
plot(rs, title="RS Line", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, color=color.white)

Comment: Got it resolved post discussion with Urso..Thanks for the Help and knowledgable discussion

Comment: @RaviKrishna  Was this changed in PineScript 5?
If I run the below code, it draws a horizontal line at the close of the very first (historical) bar.
How can I fetch and store the close price of the very last bar? So, the 'current' close price?
<code>
    //@version=5
    indicator("test", overlay=true)
    
    var MyClose = close
            
    //--- Plot curves
    plot(MyClose , title='Call test', color=color.green, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line )
</code>